# Accessing array elements with spaces in TCSH

Tags: arrays, shell, dictionary, tcsh

I'm trying to create a small little convenience script for our team.  Unfortunately, our entire build environment is based on `tcsh` for historical reasons.  In the following script, each element of `BUILD_MATRIX` is a `:` delimited pair.  I need to separate out each part of this pair for processing, but the array malfunctions for some reason.

```
#!/bin/tcsh

set BUILD_MATRIX = ( "makefile.make:make --jobs --makefile=makefile.make" \
                     "Makefile:make --jobs --makefile=Makefile" \
                     "build.xml:ant" )

foreach pair ( ${BUILD_MATRIX} )
  echo "pair: ${pair}"
end
```

gives

```
pair: makefile.make:make
pair: --jobs
pair: --makefile=makefile.make
pair: Makefile:make
pair: --jobs
pair: --makefile=Makefile
pair: build.xml:ant
```

As you can see, the array is split on spaces -- completely reasonable, but not what is desired.  How can I get `pair=makefile.make:make --jobs --makefile=makefile.make`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Csh adding strings to an array, whitespace troubles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149637/csh-adding-strings-to-an-array-whitespace-troubles)

Comment: @EtanReisner Didn't see that question, but thanks for the link.  I don't think it's quite a duplicate -- these are two different questions (albeit with similar underlying principles), so there are two different goals and two different answers.  I'll try to adapt the answer given there again to this application.

Comment: The answer there specifically covers the `foreach` case too.

Comment: @EtanReisner Whoops - my fault. I was using the brace syntax: `${array}:q` does *not* work.  I'll add that as a comment and my answer as another option.  This should be closed as a dupe.  Thanks :)

Comment: Follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27305142/1443496

Answer (score 1):

Using the linked duplicate, I was able to find a complete answer:

```
foreach pair ( $BUILD_MATRIX:q )
  set candidate = `echo $pair | sed 's/\([^:]*\):\(.*\)/\1/'`
  set command   = `echo $pair | sed 's/\([^:]*\):\(.*\)/\2/'`
  echo "pair: ${pair}"
  echo "candidate: ${candidate}"
  echo "command: ${command}"
end
```