# How can I append items to a csh list?

Tags: list, csh

I would like to create a list that will contain strings that apply to certain
conditions in csh.

How do I add to a list or array in a dynamic way without pre determining the
size of the list or the array ?

Is there is list.add or some such in the c shell ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can just use the form of `set my_list = ( $my_list more )`. For example:

```
# Create original list
% set my_list = ( hello world )
% echo $my_list
hello world

# Append to the list
% set my_list = ( $my_list hey there )
% echo $my_list
hello world hey there

# Loop over the list to verify it does what we expect it to do
% foreach item ($my_list)
foreach? echo "-> $item"
foreach? end
-> hello
-> world
-> hey
-> there
```

Comment: Use "set my_list = ($my_list:q more)" to avoid spaces problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149637/csh-adding-strings-to-an-array-whitespace-troubles