# How can I separate csh array elements with something other than a space?

Tags: arrays, csh, separator

In a csh script I'm working on I need to have array elements containing spaces, so I need to separate those elements with something other than a space, like a comma.  For example, I would like to initialize my array with something like:

```
set the_array=('Element 1','Element 2','Element 3','Element 4')
```

Note: I'm well aware of how undesirable it is to work in csh.  However, for this project I have no choice ... and yes, I've tried to convince the powers that be that this should be changed, but there is already a large code base that would have to be re-written, so that's been rejected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to initialize an array of strings (that have white spaces in them) in CSH:

The first way, using commas, uses the brace syntax, or the "glob pattern":

```
% set the_array = {'Element 1','Element 2','Element 3','Element 4'}
% echo $the_array[1]
Element 1
```

The second way, without commas, uses parentheses:

```
% set the_array = ('Element 1' 'Element 2' 'Element 3' 'Element 4')
% echo $the_array[1]
Element 1
```

This way also allows you to create an array over multiple lines:

```
% set the_array = ('Element 1' \
? 'Element 2')
% echo $the_array[1]
Element 1
% echo $the_array[2]
Element 2
```

To iterate through `the_array`, you can't simply access each element in a `foreach` as the following:

```
% foreach i ( $the_array )
foreach? echo $i
foreach? end
Element
1
Element
2
Element
3
Element
4
```

You need to loop from 1 to N, where N is the length of the array, using `seq`, shown below:

```
% foreach i ( `seq $the_array` )
foreach? echo $the_array[$i]
foreach? end
Element 1
Element 2
Element 3
Element 4
```

Note that CSH uses 1-based indexing.

Unfortunately, as you found out, using parentheses with commas will produce the following:

```
% set the_array = ('Element 1','Element 2','Element 3','Element 4')
% echo $the_array[1]
Element 1,Element 2,Element 3,Element 4
```

Sources

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80934/c-shell-array-declaration-syntax-vs
- [Csh adding strings to an array, whitespace troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149637/csh-adding-strings-to-an-array-whitespace-troubles)

Comment: Can the glob method be used over multiple lines? If so, how?  I've tried something like   `set the_arrary = { 'Element 1' \   'Element 2' \   'Element 3'  \  'Element 4' }` (with line breaks following the backslashes)  However, that leads to a "Missing }" error.

Comment: No - the glob method doesn't, but the parens method does (gotta love csh's quirks). See the above example.

Comment: :-(  Using both would save me a lot of coding.